# Cannot save file, remove write protection

Tags: windows-8

I am backing up my computer to usb hard drive. I moved many gigabytes except one folder. When I copy windows 8 says that file copy failed, that the file cannot be saved and I shall remove write protection.

External drive is not protected because I can copy anything else. I opened file properties, security tab. There are four groups: authenticated users, system and admins have all access. Users could just read and execute. I fixed it (though I am admin) but I still cannot copy the file to the external drive. Interesting is that I can copy the file to different locating on the same hard disk. But I still cannot copy this copy as well.

Comment: Try [taking ownership](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2814-take-ownership-add-context-menu-windows-8-a.html) of the folder.

Comment: I did. Meanwhile I started to copy another folder where original files were created and it failed again. Other files in this folder were copied. These files are avi videos created in pinnacle studio.